# Unable to access Windows partition from Ubuntu live USB

Tags: partitioning, windows, uefi

I have a Meegopad T01 mini PC, which has a 32-bit only UEFI firmware. I booted to my Ubuntu live USB and when I opened Gparted, I saw a lot of mmcblk0p* partitions like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

All of them have a red exclamation mark with it.

There is nothing in Nautilus. And here is a screenshot of Gnome Disks:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I can only mount the first partition (67 MB FAT). The rest seems not mountable.

And here is the log for some commands I tried:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: JetFlash Transcend 16GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Error: /dev/mmcblk0rpmb: unrecognised disk label                          

Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot0: unrecognised disk label                         

Error: /dev/mmcblk0boot1: unrecognised disk label                         

Model: MMC 032GE4 (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      20.5kB  67.1MB  67.1MB  fat32        ESP                           boot
 2      67.1MB  134MB   67.1MB               reserved                      msftdata
 3      134MB   151MB   16.8MB               boot                          msftdata
 4      151MB   168MB   16.8MB               recovery                      msftdata
 5      168MB   185MB   16.8MB               fastboot                      msftdata
 6      185MB   201MB   16.8MB               reserved_1                    msftdata
 7      201MB   268MB   67.1MB               test                          msftdata
 8      268MB   302MB   33.6MB               panic                         msftdata
 9      302MB   319MB   16.8MB  ext4         factory                       msftdata
10      319MB   336MB   16.8MB               misc                          msftdata
11      336MB   352MB   16.8MB  ext4         config                        msftdata
12      352MB   1426MB  1074MB  ext4         cache                         msftdata
13      1426MB  1695MB  268MB   ext4         logs                          msftdata
14      1695MB  2768MB  1074MB  ext4         system                        msftdata
15      2768MB  8589MB  5821MB  ext4         data                          msftdata
16      8590MB  8724MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
17      8724MB  31.3GB  22.5GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -class disk
  *-disk                  
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       size: 14GiB (16GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=0ae81fb9

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/test
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs -r /mnt/mmcblk0p17 /mnt/test
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/mnt/mmcblk0p17': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
        Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2012 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs -r /dev/mmcblk0p7 /mnt/test
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/mmcblk0p7': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/mmcblk0p7' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

So can anybody tell me how can I access the files in these partitions? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full output of both `sudo parted -l` and `sudo lshw -class disk`.

Comment: Hello David, here is the output of the commands you gave me http://tny.cz/86cc01d0

Comment: what windows version are you using?

Comment: The Windows version I'm using is Windows 8.1 Pro. I remember already disabled the hybrid boot feature.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want add relevant new information. The logs look alright. Does the NTFS partition appear in Nautilus? What about Gnome Disks? Is there any issue, when mounting it with either? The next escalation step would be to mount it manually: `mkdir -p /mnt/my_windows_partition && mount -t ntfs -r /dev/mmcblk0p17 /mnt/my_windows_partition`.

Comment: I have edited my question for more information. Tried all what you told but it seems things are not working for me.

Comment: You may have a firmware issue: This might be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Disk_device_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

The "unknown" value under "File System" for partitions 2-8 and 10 indicates that GParted couldn't recognize the filesystem(s) used on those partitions. The values under the "Name" column in your `parted -l` output indicates that these partitions probably have highly specialized purposes, so there's not much point in even trying to access them from Ubuntu; it would be like trying to access a Linux swap partition from Windows.

As a side note, you've got a number of ext4 partitions that are incorrectly marked as being Windows partitions (with the "msftdata flag"). I recommend you fix that problem, since it means that the ext4 partitions will show up in Windows as unformatted, and if you try to access them, Windows will erase their contents.

Comment: The device I have has dual-boot feature of Windows and Android, so I guess these **ext4** partitions with **msftdata** flag are for the Android system. A convenient thing is that they also do not show up when I boot to Windows. Still, even the partitions #17 with **ntfs** file system is also marked with a red exclamation mark.